# Cannot use node-hid library in electron app

Tags: electron, logitech

I had integrated **OpenTok.js** library for video call in my **electron app**, for which i want to use **logitech device** and to use it i need **node-hid** library using which my app can detect device.

I had done all the needful mentioned for using node-hid in Electron projects, package did get installed
but when i require it in my js file using :-

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
var devices = HID.devices();
```

And run my app , it gives an error

> Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 50, got 51. So please help me
>   with this issue .

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `electron-rebuild` for rebuild modules for suitable for electron. Some node modules are not exactly suitable for electron, because electron uses it's own build of Node. So, `electron-rebuild` will sort out any incompatibility or functional issues of node modules we use. The recommended way it to add `"postinstall": "electron-rebuild --force"` line to `scripts` of `package.json` file.

One other thing, on linux when you run dev mode, you have to run the script as `sudo`. Otherwise it'll rise another issue like `cannot open device with path...`

hope this help someone... :)

Comment: I have the same error and nothing is helping. I tried your solution. Also there is no webpack.config in my blank reactjs project.

Comment: I require a node-hid build for Win32 x32 / ia32, at a linux CI pipeline... Any idea? Because this prebuild for node-hid doesn't exist for Win32 x32 / ia32.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue myself, and thought I would share the solution that worked for me.  @Tharanga is correct - the recommended way to get around this is to include the below in package.json "scripts" section:

```
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild --force"
```

However, I have experienced inconsistent success with that approach.

Another approach is, after installing "node-hid", run this (if on mac):

```
    .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild
```

Or for Windows:

```
    .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

Finally, if you are using webpack in your project, you must add this line to your webpack.config.js file (within module.exports block):

```
    externals: {
        "node-hid" : 'commonjs node-hid'
    }
```

I hope this helps some folks in the future!